# Python: getting the list of wifi interfaces in linux

Tags: python, linux

Whats the most simple way to get the list of current wifi interfaces?
i guess i can just run a shell command and extract if from there, but i wonder if theres a simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using [psutil](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). You can use e.g. `net_if_stats` function to get all the network interface card names in dictionary keys. Values contain other useful info, e.g. whether the card is running (`isup`).

Filter the keys to match `wlan` which should cover the majority of cases in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway you will have to interact with the OS and Python can do it either with os or subprocess modules.

```
import os
os.system("ip link show")
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach to the ones mentioned is to read the files that describe the network interfaces. Depending on your distro/version it could be something like: `/etc/netplan` or `/etc/network/interfaces`. There are other possibilities as well, again, it depends on your specific system. They should all contain the same type of information though. I believe tools like `ip addr` read from these files.